using my trained model in the views, don't allow me to render the new return valus
it takes a while to load all the data into the new df_with_ṕredictions, my problem is how can I render the new table with those predictions in a template :
def home(request):
    df = None
    df_with_predictions = None
    error_message = None
    api_key = None
    column_name = None
    predictions_html = ""  # Initialize an empty string for the DataFrame HTML

    if request.method == 'POST':
        api_key = request.POST.get('api_key_input', '')
        column_name = request.POST.get('column_name', '')

        file = request.FILES.get('file')
        if file:
            try:
                file_ext = file.name.split(".")[-1]
                if file_ext == "csv":
                    df = pd.read_csv(file)
                elif file_ext == "xlsx":
                    df = pd.read_excel(file)

                if df is not None:
                    x_new = get_embeddings(df, column_name, api_key)
                    if x_new is not None:
                        new_predictions = classify_comments(x_new)
                        df_with_predictions = df.copy()
                        df_with_predictions['Clasificación_gpt_'] = new_predictions
                        print("File has been processed and predictions are added. in home")
                        print(df_with_predictions)
                        # Convert DataFrame to HTML
                        predictions_html = df_with_predictions.to_html(classes="table table-striped", index=False)
            except Exception as e:
                error_message = str(e)

    context = {
        'api_key': api_key,
        'column_name': column_name,
        'predictions_html': predictions_html,  # Pass the HTML to the template
        'error_message': error_message
    }
    return render(request, "home.html", context)

I tried having al the variables in one post for manipulated in the home views, but I am still having troubles
this Is what I see on the terminal:
**Predictions:
[3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 3]
File has been processed and predictions are added. in home
raiz  ... Clasificacióngpt

0    1.0  ...                  3
1    2.0  ...                  3
2    4.0  ...                  3
3   11.0  ...                  3
4   12.0  ...                  3
5   15.0  ...                  3
6   17.0  ...                  3
7   22.0  ...                  3
8   24.0  ...                  2
9    NaN  ...                  3
10   NaN  ...                  3
11   NaN  ...                  3
12   NaN  ...                  3
13   NaN  ...                  3
14   NaN  ...                  3
15   NaN  ...                  3
16  25.0  ...                  2
17  26.0  ...                  3
18   NaN  ...                  3
19   NaN  ...                  3
[20 rows x 5 columns]
[27/Apr/2024 16:06:16] "POST /home/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13738
